# How to programmatically create folders in s3 with js browser SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building an open source CRM using a MEAN stack(Mongo-Express-Angualr-Node). In one of the forms I have an upload for an order asset(notes, pictures, drawings or w/e).

I thought it would be easier to do this in the browser, so I tried to use the browser sdk for AWS. I came across this error once and figured it was a COORS issue. Added a COORS file(see COORS file below) and all was well in the world.

As soon as I tried to add some order and separate the assets based on account name. I get the error below.

COORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
      <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
      <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

Code:

```
    $scope.account.Business_Name = 'Bobs Burgers';

    $scope.creds = {
      bucket: 'someBucket',
      access_key: '###',
      secret_key: '###'
    }

    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    var params = {
      Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket+'/Insertion_order_assets/'+$scope.account.Business_Name,
      ACL: 'public-read ',
      GrantFullControl: 'Everyone'
    };

    var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket, ACL: "public-read" } });
    s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
    });
```

Returns error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/someBucket%2FInsertion_order_assets%2FBobs%20Burgers. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was I was confusing folders with buckets. A folder in S3 is just an empty object. S3 is a flat file system so there is not idea of a directory or folder.

In filesystems we think of /var/www/index.asp as a file "index.asp", in the directory of "www", with the parent directory of "var"

var

↪www

↪index.asp

In S3 it's more like a JS object of { "var": { "www": "index.asp" } }, but separated by forward slashes.

i.e. /var/www/index.asp is the complete object name.

So a "folder" in S3 is really a blank object (i.e. /var/www/).

So in my example above it would not work. What I ended up doing was creating a file in my bucket with a long name that was separated by forward slashes.

```
    var new_file_name = 'insertion_order_assets/'+$scope.account.Business_Name.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()+'/'+$scope.io.file.name.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase();
    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket }});
    var params = {
      Key: new_file_name,
      ContentType: $scope.io.file.type,
      Body: $scope.io.file,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
      $scope.io.Attchment_URL = 'https://###.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + new_file_name;
      $scope.io.$save(function(){
        $location.path("/insertionOrders/all");
      });
    }).on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
      console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
    });
```

Which created the hierarchy I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but by reading the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property), I can see some syntax errors:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({ // Don't use { params: {} }
});

s3.createBucket({
  Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket,
  ACL: "public-read-write", // changed from public-read
  CreateBucketConfiguration: {
    LocationConstraint: 'us-west-1'
  }
});
```